# Dynamically change jquery

Tags: c#, jquery

I'm moving data from 'table_source' to 'table_dest', but 'table_source' is created using repeater and is correctly creating dynamic table id.  However, I need to have the element with id="table_sourceX"  to change in the jquery function change (i.e. table_source0 becomes table_source1).  I'm just learning jquery and know this is hello world statement stuff, but here goes:

jquery

```
 //moves from source to destination table            
             //$("#table_source").on('click', 'img.move-row', function (e) {
             var tableName = "#table_source" + repCounter.ToString()
             $(tableName).click(function (e) {                 
                 alert(tableName)
                 var tr = $(this).closest("tr").remove().clone();
                 tr.find("img.move-row")
        .attr("src", "remove_image_path.jpg")
        .attr("alt", "Remove");
                 $("#table_dest tbody").append(tr);
             });

//moves from destination back to source
                 $("#table_dest").on('click', 'img.move-row', function (e) {                 
                     var tr = $(this).closest("tr").remove().clone();
                     tr.find("img.move-row")
             .attr("src", "images/add.png")
             .attr("alt", "Move");
                     $("#table_source tbody").append(tr);
                 });
```

c#

```
public int repCounter= 0;
        public string renderItem(RepeaterItem item)
        {
            object DI = item.DataItem;

            string MyVal = DataBinder.Eval(DI, "FirstName").ToString();



            string html = String.Empty;

            html = "<table id=" + "table_source" + repCounter.ToString() + " style=border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: separate;" +
    "border-spacing: 10px 50px;>" +
    "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + MyVal + "</td><td><img  alt='Move' class='move-row'id='arrowRotate' src='images/add.png' data-swap='images/minussymbol.jpg'/></td>" +
    "</tr>" +
    "</table>"; 

            repCounter++;

            return html;


  }
```

Comment: I tried to clean up details of what I meant using example.

Comment: Hi, what is this line for `//$("#table_source").on('click', 'img.move-row', function (e) {`? is this unnecessary line?

Comment: Do you want to move a `<tr> .. </tr>` from one table to another?

Comment: //$("#table_source").on('click', 'img.move-row', function (e) { is from original jquery, but I am trying to modify to that code so it will change table_source to table_sourceXXX which would correspond to the table that is being moved

Comment: so now you are trying to create a click event for each table?

Comment: Yes.  I want users to click to move data from table1 to table2.

Comment: Each table is a person and I want to move a person from one table to another and back to original table, which is why I need to change element id in jquery to match table data came from.

Comment: And what about the position in each table? Should it be same as previous?

Comment: The position does have to be the same as previous.  So if I move person 1 from table1 to table2, I need to be able to remove from table2 and move back to table1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you only have two tables or multiple and which table you're trying to move to however I've made an untested attempt.

First you should neaten up your repeater and don't dynamically create it.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTable" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <table data-id="<%# Container.ItemIndex %>" class="special-table" style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px 50px;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.FirstName") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img  alt="Move" class="move-row" id="arrowRotate" src="images/add.png" data-swap="images/minussymbol.jpg" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Then try this script. I have no doubt that it will require a little tweaking maybe with the selectors however it shouldn't be too far off.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.special-table tr').click(function() {
        var row = $(this);

        var thisTable = row.closest('table');

        //all tables - should only be two for this
        var tables = $('.special-table');

        var otherTables = $.grep(tables, function (a) {
            return a.data('id') !== thisTable.data('id');
        });

        var otherTable = $(otherTables.first());

        row.appendTo(otherTable);
    });
});
```

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: I have to dynamically create repeater tables so I can increment the table id

Comment: Use this if you need the Id <table id='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' > but the solution above shouldn't need it.

Comment: How do I use .ItemIndex on the server side?

Comment: You can only use ItemIndex inside the repeater item bound event on the server side. This is the exact same code (<table id='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' >) as you'd see in the code behind. It all gets executed server side. In the repeater item bound event I think it's item.ItemIndex, item being a RepeaterItem object